# Converting index of character in a strign to the corresponding line and column of the character in the string

Tags: python, string, parsing, character, line-numbers

**The question**

Is there any module that has a convenient function that takes a string and an index of character in it and returns line number and column number of the character in the string?

**Example**

For example I have this string with line numbers written in front of every line in square bracets and separated by a space:

> [1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>
> [2] sit amet hendrerit lorem auctor. Nulla in
>
> [3] egestas diam, sed semper justo. Ut risus nulla,
>
> [4] vulputate eget tempor in, tempor sit amet orci.
>
> [5] Etiam sollicitudin porta odio, eu dignissim est

I want to get line number and column of 45th character. It will be 2nd line 6th character(if I counted correctly)

**Why I need this**

I'm parsing a string and I want to raise exception when I can't parse something. In a more CS way: I want to parse a string containing code in certain language and if something in the code violates the rules of the language I want to raise an exception about it. And I want to include a line number and column number of character in the exception message, but I only have index of the character.

Comment: This requirement seems very specific to your application, and not difficult to just write yourself. You don't need a library for this.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using pyparsing would you? It has several methods defined to work with parsing exceptions, including functions to convert a string and an offset into a line number and column number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a simple application of the standard Python library. It's possible that the library doesn't quite have an interface which is convenient enough, but it's easy enough to write:

```py
def line_col(str, idx):
    """Returns a 2-tuple which translates string index 'idx' into
       line and column counts. 'idx' is a normal Python 0-based index;
       line and column are 1-based. So line_col(str, 0) will return (1, 1).
       The newline character is considered to be the last character of a
       line.
       The function does not check whether 'idx' is in range; if idx greater
       than or equal to the length of 'str', the result will be as though
       'str' had (idx + 1 - len(str)) extra characters (none of which are
       newlines) appended to the end
    """
    return str.count('\n', 0, idx) + 1, idx - str.rfind('\n', 0, idx)
```